# Appcelerator Studio, how to add refactoring option

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

How do i install packages related with 'refactoring' and 'hierarchy viewer' options. Eclipse seems to already have these installed but in appcelerator studio i can't find them.

Comment: Are you looking for js code refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install any Eclipse Plugin into Appcelerator Studio.

Here are some refactoring plugins:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/refactoring

Comment: which one do you recommend?

Comment: I haven't used any of them, so would love to hear which one worked best for you.